# Use grep or awk to match number range

Tags: regex, grep

I'm a novice using grep/egrep/awk and have not wrapped my head around regular expressions (bonus: a link to an introduction to regex for someone who has zero programming experience would be great).

My question revolves around matching a number range within a flat file. I have values which are ten digits. Telephone numbers...

I'm attempting to match a range of numbers that move across a range for example.

55512122041 through 55512122050 (41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, and 50).

I have been using grep to match the first value like this.

```
grep 555121204[1-9]
```

Next step is I grep for the final digit

```
grep 55512122050
```

I believe that I have not found the right way to use a regex to allow one grep.

Comment: For this specific example you can use regex (like Avinash demonstrated  below), but in general - regex is *not* the right tool to check number-ranges!

Answer (score 1):

Try the below grep command which uses `P`(*Perl regex*) parameter,

```
grep -P '55512120(?:4[1-9]|50)' file
```

OR

```
grep -E '555121204[1-9]|5551212050' file
```

This would print the lines which has the number ranges from  55512122041 to 55512122050.

If you want to print only the number then add `o` parameter to the above grep command.

```
grep -oP '55512120(?:4[1-9]|50)' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file
bar foo
5551212040 Don't match
5551212041 Match
5551212050 Match
foo bar
$ grep -P '55512120(?:4[1-9]|50)' file
5551212041 Match
5551212050 Match
```

Comment: Avinash - Thanks for the response. Unfortunately I am on SunOS 5.10 within a closed system. That option -P isn't available but I did create the example above on my personal sandbox and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For the general case, where the number range is not easy to express as a regex, Awk is probably better, as it has proper support for arithmetic.

```
awk '(($1 > 123) && ($1 < 1024)) || (($1 > 2048) && ($1 < 65536))' file
```

This prints the entire matching line; if you only want to print the second field, add `{ print $2 }` etc.

You can learn enough Awk to figure this out on your own with a good tutorial and 30 minutes; see the [Stack Overflow `awk` tag info page](/tags/awk/info) for pointers.